# Raspberry Pi Keeps old IP and adds new static IP

Tags: linux, networking, ip, raspberry-pi

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.40
broadcast 10.0.0.255
network 10.0.0.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.0.0.2
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

and `ifconfig wlan0`

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:f6:52:13:aa:82  
          inet addr:10.0.0.40  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::92f6:52ff:fe13:aa82/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2563 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:442 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:197727 (193.0 KiB)  TX bytes:53803 (52.5 KiB)
```

Problem

Using network analysing utilities, I detected that these two IPs point to the same device, also confirmed by SSH’ing into both:

- `10.0.0.6` (originally first connected IP)
- `10.0.0.40` (IP set in `interfaces` file)

The IP set in the interfaces file is correct, but for some reason, it also keeps the original IP, thus I can SSH into both of these IPs pointing to the same device.

```
rm /var/lib/dhcp/* (which contained only 1 dhcp.leases file)
```

Didn’t help either, and yes, I did reboot after I set these preferences.
Any advice?

Comment: When the problem involves multiple IP addresses, please use **`ip addr`**, not ifconfig – as the latter _still_ doesn't understand this concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple Bash script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
dhclient -r
dhclient
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Seemed to do the trick, it held onto the ip even though I removed the lease and rebooted. Might be a router error or pi error, but this fixed it.